# Java ProcessBuilder failed to execute my command

Tags: java

Without using the ProcessBuilder, I can run this command via the prompt successfully.

```
winexe --user \administrator --password foo //192.168.1.13 "msiexec /qn /i \setup.msi"
```

I am creating my ProcessBuilder via this constructor

```
ProcessBuilder(String[] commands)
```

The String[] arguments that I pass into the ProcessBuilder are as follow

```
[0] winexe
[1] --user \administrator
[2] --password foo
[3] //192.168.1.13
[4] "msiexec /qn /i \setup.msi"
```

The output looks like the below so I knew the ProcessBuilder is executing the command except the parameter that I am passing in doesn't seem to be correct.  Can anyone spot what I did wrong?

```
winexe version 0.90
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
Usage: winexe [-?|--help] [--usage] [-d|--debuglevel DEBUGLEVEL]
        [--debug-stderr] [-s|--configfile CONFIGFILE] [--option=name=value]
        [-l|--log-basename LOGFILEBASE] [--leak-report] [--leak-report-full]
        [-R|--name-resolve NAME-RESOLVE-ORDER]
        ...
```

Comment: Put every token in its own String in the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you're confusing the ProcessBuilder command line tokens with the logical groupings of the command you are trying to execute.  This command does not accept an argument "--password<space>foo", but the array's 3rd element tries nonetheless to pass such a thing.

Have you tried

```
[0] winexe
[1] --user
[2] \administrator
[3] --password
[4] foo
[5] //192.168.1.13
[6] msiexec /qn /i \setup.msi
```

?

Comment: Yup, that does the trick!  Thanks

Except [6] should be [6] msiexec /qn /i \setup.msi without the quote.  Many thanks!

Comment: Yep.  I realized that about 30 ms after submitting, and edited accordingly.  (P.S. please accept if this is indeed the correct answer.)